# Overiding the function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress plugin "Contact-form-7" and there is a function [ function wpcf7_default_form_template(){} ] in the file [ contact-form.php ]...

Now comes to the really work is I have write same function in my function.php in custom template which i create but i facing problem [ either function redclare error or plugin is not activating ]

```
<?php 
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

// check for plugin using plugin name
if ( is_plugin_active( 'contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php' ) ) {

//Code function for default form
if(! function_exists('wpcf7_default_form_template')){

function wpcf7_default_form_template() {}
}
}
?>
```

If i use the above code i don't get function redclare....

```
<?php 
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

// check for plugin using plugin name
if ( is_plugin_active( 'contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php' ) ) {

//Code function for default form

function wpcf7_default_form_template() {}
}

?>
```

Now the abovecode is what i need... i want to overide the plugin file function with my function in function.php that to on plugin activation...

Thank You!

Comment: Over ridding is not supported by the php.... bt u can do this by passing arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation the easiest way will be to modify "Contact-form-7" plugin core directly.

In my experience, updating addons / core on production server is rare thing, and most probably you won't do it.

Otherwise you can try to search hooks inside this function, they are special subsystem in wordpress to modify data at some point in functions.

Comment: Is it possible that i can overide the just the function content!!